# Is it OK to give an answer to a duplicate question, before hammering out?

Tags: discussion, dupehammer

I decided to write a short answer for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592396/class-and-structure-data-placement-c-c), where I already had my dupe hammer loaded on it.

Since there already were upvotes on it, I thought that would be a good action, to make it a useful signpost for future research.

Is this behaviour appreciated, or should I just close without leaving an answer?

Comment: People could think that you answered the question for rep and then closed it, so that no other user can submit an answers.

Comment: I would feel dirty doing that. If it's a good answer then why not put it on the dupe? Unless it's already there then what would be the point of having it on the current post?

Comment: Well, rep. What does it mean actually? I've got over that point actually (maybe not completely, but my interests have more changed to moderation recently, not only because I'm a bit hurdled from my tablet).

Comment: What Rizier said is a risk. Generally, I look at such closures with a large dose of "meh". The one thing I do find annoying is when a duplicate which is crap in its own right or which is the 1,874,105th duplicate of an extremely common question got an answer that prevents autodeletion (because the answer was upvoted or accepted).

Comment: @Louis Fair point.

Comment: I leave an answer, if and only if i think the post would benefit from an answer that caters more to the specific case in the post. A good example of this would be the thousands of return value from asynchronous function questions (JavaScript). It's a hard concept to understand for a new developer, so a specialized anser in addition to the dupe closure may help.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer didn't much more than restating the link for the duplicate :-( ... Just bad timing, and being a bit slow, as mentioned.

Comment: @Louis: You know dupe-closed questions aren't eligible for automatic cleanup *at all*?

Comment: @Deduplicator Gaaaaaaaah! Forgot about that. My comment shall live in infamy. (I would upvote your comment but I reached the limit for the day. :-/)

Comment: @gnat Yup! At east I accept the duplicate.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should just close without leaving an answer. What we want is all the answers in one place. Users shouldn't have to go from page to page looking for the answer to the question.

It's also comes across as rude and slightly mean. You've answered the question but are preventing others from doing so.

If you have more to add then leave an answer on the original.

Comment: OK, that well answers my doubts. I'll accept this, and try to improve further. (deleted my answer)

Comment: I don't see this answer on the original :D

Comment: @Brett that's because I didn't find a duplicate, nor did I vote to close this after answering