# Closing a question after answering and being downvoted

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

On [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41671846/mysql-query-not-working-in-php-works-fine-in-mysql) I saw a behavior that although it wasn't inherently and obviously bad, looked slightly fishy to me and wanted to know if there was some sort of policy or community-adopted attitude about.

User asks a question about the use of `mysqli_` in php. The problem for the user was very simple: they forgot or didn't know to write a necessary statement.

Another user with a very high rep comes around, and answers the question, but not in a particularly useful way, in my opinion: suggests to use a different approach instead `mysqli_` without explaining or answering what's wrong with the OP code, or really addressing his problem; and links to his own site in his answer.

His answer gets downvoted, and the OP comments "this is not an answer to my question" (and fairly enough, it wasn't).

I get on with posting an answer, first the typical one liner ("you forgot this statement"), then a follow up edit with the amended code, and some additional commentary.

By the time I finish my edit I see that the first answerer closed the question as a duplicate directly (more than enough rep to do it by himself).

Recapping:

- Answer that doesn't deal directly with the OP's problem, but that does link to a personal resource.
- Gets downvote and rejection
- Closes question and leave unhelpful answer in place.

Again, maybe this is perfectly normal, proper and fair; and I shouldn't bring it up at all.

But seems weird that a user with all this experience wouldn't directly see that this answer had probably a more specific question/problem
that could describe it. If we are going to close down directly all the questions that could be indirectly answered by something else on Stack Overflow, very little would pass unscathed.

And simply linking to a duplicate and closing is many times unhelpful: considering the difference in code style between this question and the duplicate, the details the OP provided, I thought that it did merit an answer.

Obviously this user thought so as well, since he provided an answer quick enough. Even if not really addressing the OP's concern.

But then closed the question very quickly, but didn't think that removal of his own answer was apropos.

Oh, and I had my answer downvoted in the process. Not by the OP, whom accepted and upvoted. But by someone else. Which in this whole thing, seemed strangely coincidental.

Is all this ok? Encouraged? Frowned up upon? Working as intended?

Comment: Meta - meta- question: is it in bad taste to link to a question/answer here? Just read "meta-effects" in another question and now I wonder if I should remove the link.

Comment: Nah, YCS can take a few downvotes. Well– maybe not *take* ("... writing bad answers for silly questions is the easiest way to achieve the goal. While voting down is spoiling people's fun and should be punished" *[source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/341311/2564301)*), but certainly can *use* a few.

Comment: A note for meta-users coming to the question: please do not encourage the original question's OP with upvotes. My wrong course of actions *doesn't make the original question any better.*

Comment: @yivi re meta-meta: the meta effect isn't bad, it only amplifies what people would normally already do because of the added exposure. So if something is downvote worthy, it will get downvoted more. If something is upvote worthy, it gets upvoted more. If something is closed but it shouldn't, its reopened in no time at all, etc. Besides: removing the link does not remove it from the edit history.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Gimby. Makes sense, exposure being always a good thing. Just didn't want to appear to be looking for "support for a cause", or anything like that. It was a genuine concern about police and SO etiquette, and suddenly thought that maybe I was confusing the matter by posting the link.

Comment: @Gimby the real life evidence is different: an *off topic duplicate question* doesn't deserve an upvote, but it gets a lot.

Comment: Related: [Answering a question, then closing it as duplicate](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286072/answering-a-question-then-closing-it-as-duplicate) and [Is it OK to give an answer to a duplicate question, before hammering out?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306150/is-it-ok-to-give-an-answer-to-a-duplicate-question-before-hammering-out).

Comment: To be honest, I don't think that mentioning another library/syntax (eg. PDO over mysqli) is necessarily bad or unhelpful. It might help future readers. Sure, it should try to address the problem of the OP as good as possible, but I see that @YourCommonSense did that in the comments, by mentioning he should use fetch, it would have been better (in my opinion) to put it in the answer as well.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## If you're gonna close the question, don't answer it.

Imo, the two actions are generally *mutually exclusive*.
If you later come to the conclusion the question is a duplicate, and you're using your dupe-hammer to single-handedly close it, remove your answer.

The point of dupe-closure is to remove duplication of content on SO. By leaving the answer, you're sending mixed signals.

Comment: (Now I'm sure I've answered some questions I've closed, somewhere. Shame on me)

Comment: How does it work in meta? Should I "accept" an answer on a "discussion" question? Does it even make sense?

Comment: @yivi: You can accept this answer if you found it helpful. The community can express their (dis)agreement with votes.

Comment: IMHO, it can _sometimes_ be appropriate to add an answer to a question that you subsequently answer: if the best dupe target you can find is ok, but it might be hard for the OP to apply its advice to their particular problem, then it's good to give an answer on the new question that summarises the relevant info from the dupe target and shows how to use it for the OP's particular case. But when you do that it may be wise to make the answer community wiki so that it doesn't look like you're sending mixed signals.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Usually, on dupe closures, a comment pointing out one or 2 specifics should be enough. If it's not, is the question really a dupe?

Comment: True enough; that's what I (mostly) do. OTOH, I've even seen a diamond mod answer & hammer in the situation I described when they needed to post a small code snippet to make their point. (Multi-line Python code posted in comments turns to mush, due to Python using indentation for block-structuring).

Comment: I've sometimes put a CW answer on Qs I wanted closed as dupe. The reason was to prevent an all too frequent scenario which is especially likely to happen in low-traffic tags: I vote to close the question as a dupe, which adds the auto-comment with link, then in the time it takes between that vote and final closure, someone comes along, follows the link in the auto-comment and posts an answer that duplicates one on the other question. OP and answerer get rep and learn that duplication *is profitable*. Adding my own CW answer usually prevents users from copying an answer from the linked Q.

Comment: @Louis: as a side-note: Copy-pasted answers should be flagged as plagiarism, when that happens, of course.

Comment: @Cerbrus Of course.

Comment: *The point of dupe-closure is it to remove duplication of content on SO.* I disagree - high-quality duplicates point to the correct answer, so they still have at least *some* value to the site. That being said, the fact that something is a duplicate doesn't necessarily mean that it ought to be deleted.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: duplicates are nothing more than signposts to high quality content. The moment you add an answer, you’re duplicating content.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, it is not just about deleting one's answer before closing the question. It is about not closing the question at all once you answered and got your answer rejected.

I feel that this is an obvious conflict of interest situation, whether you intend to act in good will or not, and I feel even more so after reading [Your Common Sense's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341653/closing-a-question-after-answering-and-being-downvoted/341661#341661).

Besides, if you answered the question in the first place, you must have considered it somewhat acceptable and it is kind of illogical to close it afterwards. If you did change your mind, a simple flag seems more appropriate, regardless of your reputation and the priviledges you earned.

EDIT : NathanOliver enlightened me about the impossibility to flag a post if you have a hammer. Not sure if such cases happen often enough for this possibility being worth implementing.

Comment: That was my gut feeling, hence my visit to meta. :)

Comment: Just a FYI: You cannot flag or provide a 1 close vote close vote if you have a hammer.  It is a all or nothing action when voting to close as a dupe.  Typically though what I do is just manually write a possible duplicate comment and let the community decide.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I wasn't sure about that. I don't know wheter such situations happen often enough that it would be worth enabling high rep users flagging these posts.

Comment: Not sure it is needed.  Whether they comment or just use their hammer it is an action that is easily reversible.  I'd rather have the devs spend their time on other things like making dupes easier to find.

Comment: I disagree with that, he could have forgotten to check for duplicates and answered the question and then he finds out there is a duplicate. That is still a proper case for him to be able to close the question as a duplicate, at least, if he deletes his answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster Being in a conflict of interest situation definitely doesn't imply bad behaviour. It implies being in a situation where something that shouldn't affect your judgment might do so. It is fine to have conflicts of interest but that makes you unfit to opine on the matters in question. I'm not saying the closing was necessarily a retaliation but merely that anyone in the same situation might have one's judgment affected by one's answer rejection, and therefore should renounce closing the question by oneself.

Comment: @NathanOliver Well, you _could_ edit out the tag that you have the gold badge for, vote to dupe-close, and then edit the tag back in. But that would be bizarre. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring That is one way to work around it.  Thanks for the idea

Comment: @NathanOliver No worries. FWIW, I occasionally have the opposite problem: I attempt to hammer a Python question, but it doesn't get closed because the OP neglected to add the generic `python` tag, they only have a version-specific tag. And even if I notice that before voting I still can't hammer it (without the co-operation of another SO member) because you can't hammer a question if you add the tag yourself. Thank goodness for Chat rooms. :)

Answer (score -2):

You are right, I should have deleted my answer after finding a proper duplicate.

I don't do it due to bad temper, because I assume downvotes as a kind of forcing me to do so, and I don't like to be forced.

Besides, as this question have an accepted answer, it won't make any difference if I delete my own answer - there be "mixing signals" still. So I decided to leave it in place as it's indeed a good recommendation, that supplements an existing  answer/closure. Having simple prepare/execute/fetch routine is better than that mess one have to write using mysqli making it very easy to overlook a step.

As of the timeline - for this particular kind of question it takes time to find a proper duplicate, much more time than to write an answer, and the only motivation you have is to make this world a little bit cleaner. So, initially, I had not enough motivation to waste my life for finding a duplicate. So I decided to leave a comment with a direct solution and then answer with a better *approach.*

But after getting rather unfriendly response from the OP, I got my motivation all right, so formulated a good qoogle query and found a duplicate.

Last thing

> And simply linking to a duplicate and closing is many times unhelpful: considering the difference in code style between this question and the duplicate, the details the OP provided, I thought that it did merit an answer.

You are simply wrong here. This is a textbook duplicate case.

Comment: I don't understand what are you talking about. Do you mean that a duplicate shouldn't be closed or what?

Comment: Pretty much what @yivi said. Don't take votes personally. I think the closure is fine if it's indeed a duplicate, but if you _know_ a question is a duplicate, don't answer it.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, though! I wholeheartedly agree with your "for this particular kind of question it takes time to find a proper duplicate" – I've had this happen while I was searching the web and cobbling up something, and in that time someone who was familiar with the issue at hand came along, knew exactly what to look for, and dupe-hammered it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense if you get so angry roaming the `php`+`mysql` tags,  then just ignore them. I have been following your questions and answers on meta for quite a while now, and while I wholeheartedly believe in your cause, I also believe it is a lost one. I have currently ignored the `C#` and `regex` tags, because if yours are _anything_ like those, it's a cesspool of people with no interest to learn nor teach, no ability to read nor write English and in general just a bunch of people copy-pasting bad advice towards people who don't know what they're doing. All of them are unsaveable.

Comment: @Cerbrus I think everyone knows that (theoretically), but once in a while I also find myself being annoyed by a downvote, I guess we're just humans.

Comment: @g00glen00b: I get annoyed by downvotes all the time. I don't act on that annoyance, though.

Comment: @Cerbrus still I don't get what's wrong with the act taken

Comment: @Cerbrus True, but he acted by doing something he should/could have done the whole time. I have mixed feelings about this "right thing for the wrong reason" thingy, is it good? is it bad?

Comment: YourCommonSense / @g00glen00b: The closure isn't wrong. YCS shouldn't have answered it.

Comment: @Cerbrus I agree with that.

Comment: "But after getting rather unfriendly response from the OP, I got my motivation all right, so formulated a good qoogle query and found a duplicate."  ...Just to be clear, you _do_ realise that you outright admitted that you put in extra effort looking for a duplicate, so you could close the question, as a form of retaliation, right?  If you didn't feel it was worth the effort to find a duplicate in the first place, then being told that your answer didn't actually solve the OP's problem shouldn't have changed that.  No offense, but that just reeks of spite.

Comment: @JustinTime with all due respect, I would rather refrain from discussing my personality here. the question is about the proper course of actions for the question closure. What do I feel or what do i realize is a slightly off topic here.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Fair enough.

Comment: If you weren't acting purely emotionally, which makes it relate to your personality... then yes. If you react passionately and emotionally.. then I believe at least addressing that part of the issue is important. It's not like you purely acted here without emotion.... We can discuss the proper action to take... but part of it IS "don't let your emotions get the better of you"...

Comment: @Patrice the question is about closure. If you feel an urge to discuss someone's personality, ask another question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Discussing your personality would be off-topic (and arrogant given we don't know you beyond your contribution to SO, which otherwise appears to be highly commendable). What is on topic is discussing the fact that you (or anyone else in the same situation) were arguably in a situation where you shouldn't have used this privilege. It is absolutely not about you, it is about a situation where emotional matters might affect rational judgement and about what is good practice in such situations.

Comment: It's not about your personality. It's about the closure. And closing things out of spite is wrong. IMO, If you feel "wronged" and feel the urge to close a question because of that, you should just step back, comment on it, and let the community deal with it. Even more so (as it was in this case) when if your first impulse was to actually answer the question.

Comment: @yivi were your community able to deal with *anything*, were would have been no need for the hammer privilege. Alas, there is no community and nobody to deal with a question. My first impulse was wrong and the closure was right. Your question is a dupe. The case is closed.

Comment: **Moderator note**: Please do keep the conversation constructive. I've cleaned up this thread, removing obsolete comments (referencing language from a previous edit) as well as discussion that overly focuses on personalities, motivations and emotions. There is always chat if you want to discuss further.