# Update delay of newest badge and false information on popup

Tags: bug, badges, profile-page, popup

I spotted this bug on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com). As the template is quite identical I suspect that the bug appears in the main site too, and for the worst case in the entire SE network.

My newest badge is [Excavator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/75/excavator?userid=2408342), and it was awarded for,

- [Closing a question after answering and being downvoted [duplicate]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341653/closing-a-question-after-answering-and-being-downvoted)

But in my profile's activity tab, the badge has not been updated yet. It shows the [Good Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=2408342) badge which was awarded previously for.

- [How could I have handled this situation better?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371145/how-could-i-have-handled-this-situation-better)

In the popup for the [Good Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=2408342) badge the *Awarded for:* link shows the post which the [Excavator](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/75/excavator?userid=2408342) badge was awarded.

[image]

---

> **This link has nothing to do with [Good Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=2408342) badge**.

However, if I click [Learn more](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/21/good-question?userid=2408342) option, then the correct data is being shown.

[image]

---

There's a delay of updating the newest badge on the profile page, but the information in the popup for the relevant badge updates without a delay.

Comment: Right, sorry, I didn't read properly. Tag removed.

Comment: Same for most of my badges. I always wait 10mn or less and my badges is notified and published everywhere. This is probably due to a low-priority queue inside a large propagation + verification network.